# Proof of the second principle of mathematical induction

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, induction

This was an exercise in my lecture notes for which no answer was provided, so I seek verification on whether my proof is correct.

Prove that if
1. $P(n_0)$ is true for some $n_0 \in \mathbb N$, and if
2. $\forall k \in \mathbb N : k \ge n_0 : P(n_0) \land P(n_0 + 1) \land \ldots P(k - 1) \land P(k)$ true $\Rightarrow P(k + 1)$  is true,
then $P(n)$ is true $\forall n \in \mathbb N, n \ge n_0$.

**Proof**
Let $S = \{x \in \mathbb N: x \ge n_0: P(x)$ is false$\}$.
If $S$ is non-empty, then S contains a minimum element by the well-ordering principle of $\mathbb N$, call it $m$, where clearly $m \ne n_0$.
Then $P(n_0), P(n_0 + 1), \ldots, P(m - 2), P(m-1)$ cannot be false, which implies $P(m)$ is true; a contradiction.
Therefore $S$ = $\emptyset$ and $P(n)$ is true $\forall n \ge n_0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this proof is correct. Nice work!

Comment: This should've been a comment. You have enough reputation points to comment.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: Why the flag and recommended deletion?  It's nothing profound, but the question is simply seeking verification for a proof, without any further specific question, and Glare's answer is correct. @Robert: It is not a "thank you" answer.

Comment: Yeah, I was a little confused about that. I checked the tag wiki, and there's nothing on there about having to respond in comment form on proof-verification posts if a proof is absolutely correct. If this is indeed a rule/custom, is there a meta SE post or guideline page you could direct me to @RobertSoupe?

Comment: The canned messages for the reviewers are not always the best; I should have chosen "no comment necessary" on this one. But the asker didn't say "I just want a yes or no answer." Although he seems to be satisfied with it. I would have wanted some elaboration, something like "This proof is technically correct but it could be simpler because..." or "This proof looks a lot like a proof I saw in such and such book..."

Comment: @Glare, I don't know if it's a rule, but I do think it's a custom. Anyone can say "Yes, it's correct." Not everyone can say "Yes, it's correct because" and then go on to explain why it's correct and whether or not it's the most efficient way to prove it.