# To prove stronger form of mathematical induction

Tags: solution-verification, induction

Let $P(n$) be a statement about positive integers and

1. $P(1)$ is true
2. For every positive $k \in \mathbb{N}$, if $P(k)$ is true for all $k<m$, then $P(m )$ is true

Then we may conclude that $P(n)$ is true $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Now I assume for the sake of contradiction that this is not the case. So, there exists some $n_0$ such that $P(n_0)$ is false. I collect all these in a set, say
$S = \{ n \in \mathbb{N}|\text{$P(n)$ is false} \}$, so by the well-ordering principle it has least element, say $r$. So $P(r)$ is false and $r$ is minimum. So for all natural numbers less that $r$, $P(n)$ is true. But by hypothesis if $P(n)$ is true for all numbers less than $r$, then $P(r)$ is also true. This is a contradiction. Thus strong induction is valid.

I am not sure if this is correct. Could someone review my proof?

Comment: if the upvotes haven't told you already, the proof is fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of the second principle of mathematical induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119864/proof-of-the-second-principle-of-mathematical-induction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to remove it from the list of unanswered questions. Yes your proof is **perfectly fine.** It's indeed **correct.**